# Image not moving to proper folder zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, image-uploading

I started working on Zend Framework image upload.The code is not showing any errors but image not moving to proper destination.

```
public function uploadAction()
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $form = new UploadForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) 
        {
            $profile = new Upload();
            $form->setInputFilter($profile->getInputFilter());

            $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
            $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('fileupload');
            $data = array_merge_recursive($request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray());
            //print_r($data);die;
            //set data post and file ...
            $form->setData($data);

            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {

                 $favicon = $data['fileupload']['name'];
                 $ext = pathinfo($favicon, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                 $faviconnewname = "_favicon." . $ext;
                 $favadapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
                 $favadapter->setDestination('public/img/upload'); //upload destination
                 $favadapter->addFilter('Rename', $faviconnewname, $favicon);
                 if($favadapter->receive($favicon))
                 {
                     echo "suceess";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     echo "Failed";
                 }
                 die;
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

The image is not received and gives failed message.Can you solve this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: try this $favadapter->setDestination('public/img/upload/'); //upload destination

Comment: @DilDilshan Not working

Comment: make sure that folder exists in the server and is with write permission

Comment: @DilDilshan I tried file upload in simple PHP it works fine in simple PHP code but not working in zend framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write *"gives failed message"* so apparently something goes wrong. You should try to find out what and why... All we can do is guess with the information you are giving inside your question.

If you read the ZF2 documentation on this file adapter class **[here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html)** then you can see that the adaper has a `getMessages` method. This might give you some insight on what actually goes wrong:

```
$adapter = new Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
$adapter->setDestination('public/img/upload');

if (!$adapter->receive()) {
    $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
    echo implode("\n", $messages);
}
```

This code snippet comes straight out of the official docs!

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem which was due to filters :)

Answer (score 1):

Your final running code make sure you comment filters

```
public function uploadAction()
    {
        error_reporting(0);
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $form = new UploadForm($em);
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) 
        {
            $profile = new Upload();
            $form->setInputFilter($profile->getInputFilter());

            $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
            $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('fileupload');
            $data = array_merge_recursive($request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray());
            //print_r($data);die;
            //set data post and file ...
            $form->setData($data);

            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {  
                 $favicon = $data['fileupload']['name'];
                 $ext = pathinfo($favicon, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                 $faviconnewname = "_favicon." . $ext;
                 $favadapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
                 $favadapter->setDestination('public/img/upload/'); //upload destination
                 //$favadapter->addFilter('Rename', $faviconnewname, $favicon);
                 if (!$favadapter->receive())
                 {
                     $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
                     echo implode("\n", $messages);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     echo "success";
                 }
                // die;
            }
        }
//        if ($request->isPost()) 
//        {
//            $fname = $_FILES['fileupload']['name']; 
//            $tmp_name = $_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"];
//            $uploads_dir = 'public/img/upload';
//            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$uploads_dir/$fname"))
//            {
//                echo "Uploaded";
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                echo "Error";
//            }
//        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
```